# Children in firebase are deleted after I close the app, how to let the data stay?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's how I put value in firebase:

```
 exDBKey1 = exerciseList.get(position).getExerciseId();
                        exerciseName = exerciseList.get(position).getExerciseName();
                        weekExerciseModel = new WeekExerciseModel(exerciseName, exDBKey1);


executedExercises.child(userID).child("WeeklyExercises").child(exerciseWeek)
                            .child(exerciseDay).push().setValue(weekExerciseModel);
```

Here's my firebase which gets deleted after I re-open the app:

[image]

The dynamic data are from this code

```
exerciseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    WeekExerciseModel weekExerciseModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(WeekExerciseModel.class);

                    if("Very Active".equalsIgnoreCase(weekExerciseModel.getStatus()) &&
                            "1".equalsIgnoreCase(weekExerciseModel.getExerciseDay()) &&
                            "2".equalsIgnoreCase(weekExerciseModel.getExerciseWeek()) &&
                                "Gain".equalsIgnoreCase(weekExerciseModel.getUserGoal())
                            && "None".equalsIgnoreCase(weekExerciseModel.getUserDisease())){


                        exerciseList.add(weekExerciseModel);

                        Log.e("exercisenameSnapshot", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.getKey()));

                    }
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("FitureUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("exerciseIDW2D1", weekExerciseModel.getExerciseId());
//                    editor.putInt("exerciseSum",day);
                    editor.putString("exerciseDay","Day 1");
                    editor.putString("exerciseWeek","Week 2");
                    editor.putString("exercisenameSnapshot", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.getKey()));
                    editor.apply();
```

It looks like this after it gets deleted
[image]

Comment: This code is okay or instead of giving value dynamically please try it once using static values. 
`executedExercises.child(userID).child("WeeklyExercises").child(exerciseWeek)
                            .child("exerciseday").push().setValue("weekExerciseModel");`  If your data is still getting deleted then please upload more code to SO.

Comment: Have you implemented `onStop`, `onPause` or `onDestroy` methods? If yes, please add them to your question.

Comment: it's still the same problem

Comment: @AlexMamo no i didn't yet

Comment: Why do you say it gets deleted? The db remains empty?

Comment: It stores the data but after I move to another fragment or close the app the children ends up being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the same Parent node which later I found out that is what's causing the wiped out data. So I made a new Parent node still the same process but it only contains the data that I need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with static values but also try

```
executedExercises.child(userID).child("WeeklyExercises").child(exerciseWeek).child(exerciseDay).setValue(weekExerciseModel);
```

And see if this helps.

Also, how are you calling your firebase database path - `.getInstance().getReference()` line when you open the app?
My next question would be on why you have a key map of exDBKEY1 in your weekExerciseModel but the key name is showing as exerciseID in your database when it probably should show as exDBKEY1 just like how your exerciseName variable shows as exerciseName for the key name. You might need to show more of the code such as where the exerciseID comes form because it looks like a firebaseUID which means it's going to the database to get it which could be clearing out your data from wherever else the code for that UID is.

Comment: exDBKey1 is actually exerciseID , I just forgot to change it. The UID is from another fragment and i used sharedpreference to get it.

Comment: I also have tried using static values and data still gets deleted in firebase.

Comment: This might be an async issue of when you try to get the data there is no data to receive until the async task is finished so, in an attempt to write data to the `List`, it wipes out the data. If possible, debug to see if your Log datasnapshot.getkey value is done after the database wipes out or before just to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Yes, I used breakpoint just to be sure and I found out that it's done before it gets deleted from the database.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what it looks like after it gets deleted please?

Comment: I edited my question and I put a picture after it gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks that'll help us. Out of my own nagging curiosity can you do two things please. I know you've tried static values but have you tried it as such: 1)  `executedExercises.child(userID).child("WeeklyExercises").setValue(weekExerciseModel);`  and use `weekExerciseModel = new WeekExerciseModel(exerciseName, exDBKey1);` with `exerciseName = "dragonfly"`, `exDBKey1 = "test1"`;     
2. At which breakpoint did that node wipe out?

Comment: It wiped out after I clicked another fragment or after I re-open the app.

Comment: Where is the userID being referenced? and can you temp move the 'weekly exercise, exercise name' block of code to where you are setting the data for age, bmi...etc? and see if it wipes out? Probably not. Hopefully not. Or is all of this already in the same fragment&block/scope?

Comment: I'm thinking whenever the age, bmi, goal values are set on reopen, if they are being set on the app opening, since they are directly being set as executedExercisesRef children, then it is wiping out the database. And a change of the fragment is calling that `.setValue()` again somehow. That's my prognosis as of now.

Comment: It's not in the same fragment. Actually It's in an adapter

Comment: Your adapter might be getting called when the app opens and again when the fragment stack ends. Just to clarify the process: You open the app and the your age bmi etc values are still in the database but the weeklyinfo is cleared out. Also, when you do a fragment for the weeklyinfo it sets those values then on a fragment change, the data is erased? Add your age, bmi, to another child of executedExercises ex: executedExercises.child(userInfo).setValue(age, bmi, etc) and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I solved it! I needed to find an alternative way so I just made a new Parent node and put all the data there and it didn't wipe out after I open other fragments/activities. Thank you though, you helped a lot!